# How to check stock prices online?

Tags: stocks

I do not know anything about stock market. However, I got interested in it and I want to know about it. I want to know how I can check the prices and to know the companies which sell their stock online.
Is it possible to see all the price of the shares of companies from the most expensive to the cheapest?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are a lot of places you can research stocks online, Google Finance, Yahoo Finance, Reuters etc.

It's important to understand that the price of the stock doesn't actually mean anything.  Share price is just a function of the market capitalization divided by the number of shares outstanding.  As an example take two companies that are both worth $1 million, but Company A has issued 10,000 shares and Company B has issued 100,000 shares.  Company A has a share price of $100 while Company B has a share price of just $10.  Comparing share price does nothing to indicate the relative value or health of Company A versus Company B.

I know there are supposed to be no product recommendations but the dictionary area of investopedia.com is a good source of beginner investing information.  And as Joe points out below the questions here with the "stock" tag would also be a good place to start.  And while I'm on a roll, the book "A Random Walk Down Wall Street" is a good starting point in investing in the stock market.

Comment: I was thinking he might just spent a bit of time reading all the questions here with "stock" tag. Like any blog, investopedia has its good and bad articles. One article regarding Roth conversions had some awful math. I commented and the author was dismissive. YMMV

Comment: I want to know about those websites which show the price from highest to lowest as if I am shopping.

Comment: @MOON the share price difference between different companies doesn't matter.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer The `dictionary` section on investopedia is generally okay, though.

Comment: @MOON are you suggesting groupon is a better buy than Apple (strictly looking at price)?

Comment: @dg99 for what it's worth I specified the dictionary area after Joe's comment...

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer. I must have the money to buy at least one share. For example one share of Google is 750 dollar so it is expensive. I thought buying shares which are for example 50 dollar per share.

Comment: @MOON A share price of $50 and $750 are the same thing from a profit perspective. The dollar amount of your profit is a function of how much money you put in to begin with. $50 might turn into $100 if you're really lucky, but it'll never turn into $50,000. If your goal is to invest in stocks, you'll need to put in tens of thousands of dollars to make a 20% return mean anything. At that point, picking stocks based on their price doesn't make a material difference.

Comment: @MOON you really can't 'go shopping'  for stocks like you can for underwear. The cheapest stock prices are not the best buys. I recommend you get with a financial planner to help you understand the nature of investing.